# Pytest + Coverage generates wrong coverage

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

I have a source code structure that looks like this

- src

  - main.py
- test

  - default_case

    - test_default.py

Then if I run coverage against the test folder

```sh
coverage run --source test -m py.test
```

It gives me

```
$ poetry run coverage report
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------
test/default/test_default.py      35      1    97%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             35      1    97%
```

If I run it against the source (`src`) folder

```
$ poetry run coverage report
Name          Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------
src/main.py     105    105     0%
---------------------------------
TOTAL           105    105     0%
```

I get no coverage.

In my test, I run `main.py` as a child process.

Then I switched to run `main()` function inside `main.py` and the coverage result turned out to be the same.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging, combining the [Coverage official tutoria](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/)l and [this github thread](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/876), the problem was solved.

```
cd /path/to/project_root
poetry run coverage run --omit '*virtualenvs*' -m pytest
poetry run coverage report -m
```

Note that I use poetry to manage my dependencies, so you should remove `poetry run` if you don't use poetry.